# pdf transformation of periodic scalar random variables related by a derivative

Tags: probability-distributions, transformation, inverse-function, periodic-functions, inverse-function-theorem

Two random scalar variables, x and y, are related by the following expression: $y(t) = f[x(t)] = a\frac{dx(t)}{dt}$, where $x(t)$ is periodic and $a$ is a constant.

How can I calculate the pdf $g_{Y}[y(t), t]$, knowing the pdf $g_{X}[x(t), t]$?

I'm confusing myself on how to apply
$g_{Y}(y, t)=g_{X}(x=f^{-1}(y), t)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|_{y=y}$

Comment: You will in general not be able to calculate the pdf of $y(t)$ by knowing the pdf of $x(t)$ (only at a single point). A well-known example where we know something is Brownian motion $y(t)$ and its integral $x(t)=\int_0^ty(s)\,ds\,.$ This $x(t)$ is normal with mean zero and [variance $t^3/3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1336471/949989).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @KurtG. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by knowing the pdf of $x(t)$ only at a single point. To make it clear, I know (not analytically though) the entire pdf of $x$, in the entire $x$ domain, and at any $t$. Does this change anything?

Comment: After a few edits $x(t)$ is differentiable, periodic and random. Taking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1368109/949989) as hint does not leave a lot of possibilities for it and leads to an expression for $y(t)\,.$